# Vertical arrangement of subfigure beside a long listing and equation

Tags: captions, minipage, subcaption, subfig

I am using the env `lstlisting` and `subfigure` in the `figure`. Since I am running out of space, I'd like to put image B on top of image A with their own captions. I'd also keep the general caption. Any suggestion?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
while(a<0){
a++;
long code
...
...
...
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{listing 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \begin{align*}
            &F_1(a, b)  \\ 
            &F_2(a, b)  \\ 
            &F_1(a, b)  \\ 
            &F_2(a, b)  \\ 
        \end{align*}
        \caption{eqation 2}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-a}
        \caption{image 1}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \noindent\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image-b}
    \caption{image 1}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{general caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

At the moment the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You can insert both images in the same `subfigure` followed by their captions but between them had to be inserted an empty line:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[skip=0.25ex,belowskip=1ex]{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\noindent\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
while(a<0){
a++;
long code
...
...
...
}
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{listing 1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
        \begin{align*}
            &F_1(a, b)  \\
            &F_2(a, b)  \\
            &F_1(a, b)  \\
            &F_2(a, b)  \\
        \end{align*}
        \caption{eqation 2}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{image 1}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{image 2}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{general caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An elegant solution, thanks! How would you increase vertical space between images A and B?

Comment: @sepideha, by inserting for example `\medskip` before second `\includegraphics` or define spaces as options for `subcaptions`. See edited answer.